# Отличающийся стиль именования std::_Exit

Tags: c++, стандарт, дизайн-языка, std

Почему функция `std::_Exit` имеет отличающийся от других идентификаторов стандартной библиотеки стиль именования? Обычно всё именуется с маленькой буквы с `_` для разделения слов, а идентификаторы, начинающиеся с `_` и заглавной буквы зарезервированы для внутреннего использования.

Comment: *"зарезервированы для внутреннего использования"* Стандартной библиотеке можно.

Comment: То что данный стиль именования идентификаторов зарезервирован для внутреннего пользования означает, что вы не можете так именовать свои собственные идентификаторы, но идентификаторы в стандартной библиотеке / ключевые слова языка так именоваться могут. Более того, в любой момент в язык  можно добавить новый идентификатор вида «символ подчёркивания+заглавная буква» не опасаясь конфликтов имён с пользовательским кодом. Вероятно данная функция имеет такой стиль именования по соображениям совместимости. См.: [Why are C booleans called _Bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47821877)

Comment: @wololo, но это не ключевое слово и даже не имя в глобальном неймспейсе.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, но `_Exit` — это Сишная функция, и там её просто так в `std` не запакуешь. А даже если и запакуешь, то имя `std::exit` [уже занято](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit).